# Disappearing DOM elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Starting with an XML file, like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<document id="id1">
  <elemone id="id2"></elemone>
  <elemtwo id="id3"></elemtwo>
</document>
```

, fetching the file using `XMLHttpRequest` like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

var resp = e.target
if (resp.status == 200 &&
        resp.responseXML != null &&
        resp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('document')) { 
                    xhrProcess(resp.responseXML);       
    }
}, false);
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/example.xml");
xhr.send();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/example.xml");
xhr.send();
```

, then parsing it like this:

```
var xhrProcess = function(data) {
    var DOMSubElement = null;
    var DOMOtherElement = document.body;

    switch (data.firstElementChild.tagName) {
    // ...
    case 'document':
        DOMSubElement = data.firstElementChild.getElementsByTagName('elemone')[0];
        DOMOtherElement.appendChild(DOMSubElement);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

, **my elements seem to "disappear"**. If the `switch` case matches, I get `undefined` and *DevTools* shows `<elemone>` is missing:

```
data: XMLDocument
​​...       
childElementCount: 1    ​​
childNodes: NodeList(1)​​​
    0: document#id1
    ...  
    childElementCount: 1    ​​​​
    childNodes: NodeList(4)   ​​​​​
        0: #text​​​​​
        1: #text​​​​​
        2: elemtwo#id3
        3: #text    ​​​​​
        length: 4
```

, however, if the `switch` case doesn't match, `<elemone>` "comes back":

```
data: XMLDocument​​
...
​​childElementCount: 1​​
childNodes: NodeList(1)​​​
    0: document#id1​​​​
    childElementCount: 2​​​​
    childNodes: NodeList(5)​​​​​
         0: #text​​​​​
         1: elemone#id2
         2: #text​​​​​
         3: elemtwo#id3
         4: #text​​​​​
         length: 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `... && resp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('document'))` will always be true because `.getElementsByTagName()` always returns something that is truthy.

Comment: If that's (`.responseXML`) the result of the parser then your XML is malformed. Check the content of `.responseText`.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, the code is all over a bit, my bad... due to the subject matter, I was changing bits of code, and there I removed the original indexing operator `[]` at the end.

Comment: @Andreas `responseText: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n<document id=\"id1\">\n\t<elemone id=\"id2\"></elemone>\n\t<elemtwo id=\"id3\"></elemtwo>\n</document>"`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/9rf1cbsz/ -> Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: @Andreas xhrProcess got called twice, appending an element with the same index. I have to figure out when it's called. I've edited the jsfiddle so it reflects this. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/ap1jbwvt/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212283/discussion-between-hatebit-and-andreas).

Comment: `.appendChild()` removes the element from where-ever it came from. If this is not your intent then clone the element before appending it somewhere else

Comment: @Andreas You can make that as an answer...